# Does JMeter support to test mobile application?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Can we test mobile application either iOS/Android(Native/hybrid)App using Apache JMeter? If yes, what's the way?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test mobile application directly i.e. how long does it take to load, how responsive it is, etc. via JMeter. What you can do with JMeter is to simulate large number of mobile devices talking to your backend server to measure performance and also apply some client-side assertions to make sure that server's response is not malformed.

It is possible to record mobile application network activity via [JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as follows:

1. Add aforementioned HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and a [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) to Workbench
2. Make sure that host, running JMeter and mobile device are on the same network (i.e. use Wifi, not cellular data plan) and the host running JMeter is accessible (i.e. firewall software doesn't block port 8080)
3. Start JMeter's proxy
4. Configure device to use JMeter's proxy.
5. Launch your application and perform necessary actions
6. When you finished stop JMeter's proxy and copy recorded requests to Test Plan
7. Perform correlation and parametrization if needed
8. Configure Thread Group virtual users and ramp-up according to your load scenario.
9. Launch the tests
10. Analyze results

References:

- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy)
- [Parametrization in JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/parameterization.html)
- [Guide to JMeter Regular Expressions](https://flood.io/blog/28-guide-to-jmeter-regular-expressions)